# How to uninstall firefox add-on using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

Hi All. Please help me. I am new in firefox extension development and I have a problem. I want to remove my add-on from user machine if user go for a particular website which is provided by our client. Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to uninstall Firefox Add on using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310726/how-to-uninstall-firefox-add-on-using-javascript)

Comment: before this gets closed again, what have you tried?

Comment: I have already told i have client requirement. Actually this addon has two version one light and other is advance In light version user can view this add on only on few sites which will provide by us. plz answer thanks

Comment: Plz reply it is possible or not

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible only with javascript, since it needs access to the filesystem. With flash or java maybe...but I doubt it.